# React table row selection

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I've followed below link and tried to construct a table grid which includes row selection.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/row-selection

But for some reason it's not working. It's allowing me to select any two rows. When I select 3rd row the previous selection isn't remembered.

Here is the code snippet.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { ContentWrapper } from "@nextaction/components";
import { useTable, useRowSelect, usePagination } from "react-table";
import $ from "jquery";
import { Row, Col, Button, Badge } from "reactstrap";

import FETCH_XXXXX_QUERY from "../queries/FetchXXXXXQuery";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
  ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef();
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

    React.useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

    return (
      <>
        <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
      </>
    );
  }
);

function XxxxxxGrid({ columns, data, prospectData }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    selectedFlatRows,
    state: { selectedRowIds },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      prospectData,
    },
    useRowSelect,
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
        // Let's make a column for selection
        {
          id: "selection",
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox
          Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
        },
        ...columns,
      ]);
    }
  );

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.slice(0, 10).map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const Xxxxxxxx = ({ actions, history }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);

  const gridData = React.useMemo(() => (data ? data.xxxxx.data : []), [data]);

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("ALL");

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "contactName",
        Cell: function (props) {
          return (
            <span>
              <b>
                <Link to={"/xxxxx/" + props.row.original.id}>
                  {props.value}
                </Link>
              </b>
              <br></br>
              <span>{props.row.original.title}</span>
              <br></br>
              <Link to={"/xxxxx/" + props.row.original.id}>
                {props.row.original.accountName}
              </Link>
            </span>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        Header: "Cadence",
        accessor: "accountName",
        Cell: function (props) {
          return (
            <span>
              <b>
                <Link to={"/xxxxxxxx/" + cadence.id}>{props.value}</Link>
              </b>
            </span>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        Header: "Tags",
        accessor: "tag",
        Cell: function (props) {
          return (
            <Badge color="secondary" pill>
              {props.value}
            </Badge>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        Header: "C Outcome",
        accessor: "phone",
      },
      {
        Header: "E Outcome",
        accessor: "title",
      },
      {
        Header: "Last Contact",
        accessor: "createdDate",
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const XxxxxxGrid = React.useMemo(
    () => (
      <XxxxxxGrid
        columns={columns}
        data={gridData}
        prospectData={prospectData}
      />
    ),
    [gridData]
  );

  return (
    <ContentWrapper>
      <div className="content-heading pb-0">
        <div>
          <em className="fa fa-user fa-lg"></em> Prospects
        </div>
        <div className="ml-auto">
          <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a
                href="#"
                className={
                  "nav-link text-center" +
                  (activeTab === "xxxx" ? " active" : "")
                }
              >
                <h4 className="text-primary">1522</h4>
                <h6>xxx</h6>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a
                href="#"
                className={
                  "nav-link text-center" +
                  (activeTab === "xxxx" ? " active" : "")
                }
              >
                <h4 className="text-primary">1522</h4>
                <h6>xxxx</h6>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a
                href="#"
                className={
                  "nav-link text-center" +
                  (activeTab === "xxxx" ? " active" : "")
                }
              >
                <h4 className="text-primary">1522</h4>
                <h6>xxx</h6>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a
                href="#"
                className={
                  "nav-link text-center" +
                  (activeTab === "xxxxxx" ? " active" : "")
                }
              >
                <h4 className="text-primary">1522</h4>
                <h6>xxxxx</h6>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Col sm={4}>
          <div className="input-group pl-0">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
              aria-describedby="button-addon2"
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <Button
                color="outline-secondary"
                type="button"
                id="button-addon2"
              >
                <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="border-bottom border-top">
        <div className="ml-auto">
          <Button color="outline">
            <em className="fas fa-file-csv text-primary"></em>&nbsp; Import CSV
          </Button>
          &nbsp;|
          <Button color="outline">
            <em className="fa fa-plus text-primary"></em>&nbsp; Add
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Row>
      <Row>{!loading && XxxxxxGrid}</Row>
    </ContentWrapper>
  );
};

export default Xxxxxxxx;
```

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox of your code instead of sharing codesandbox of the referred link

Comment: Code sandbox goes to a 404 currently.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me,
in my case the bug was generated due to a conflict with the StrictMode generated by default in index.js.

Try to Delete it

```
ReactDOM.render (
<React.StrictMode>
<App />
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById ('root')
```

the Index should look like this:

```
ReactDOM.render (
<App />,
document.getElementById ('root')
```

Comment: The link you refer to at the end is the exact link the OP said they were working from, and that it wasn't working. I'd recommend deleting that part of your answer.